# GZip from a File that contains text data as well

Tags: java, gzip

We get a gzip file via MQ and this has some message properties appended to the stream as well. Can we read the gzip data from the stream and unzip it? If this is possible, please could you give some pointers. Thank you.

Comment: Was able to get this out from the Byte Array and unzip it as well. Had to do a little bit of skipping to get to the start of the stream.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. My need tweaking (not tested).

Edit:

```
GZIPInputStream gz = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(gz);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
    sb.append(line);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: This won't compile; the `while` expression needs to be a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

read function return the actual number of bytes read. So you should store the return value of this function (currently inside while check in your code). When this value is != -1 and is < 1024 then it gives you the idea that where gzip data ends and string data starts.